# .NET Core 2.1 app publishes from VS2017 but not command line?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publishing

I turned OFF the TreatWarningsAsErrors, as i kept getting errors when publishing while self-contained is set to true.  Now VS2017 publishes successfully, but the command line dotnet publish still reports the same errors.  How can fix this?

Example of the errors i receive: 
**error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0.  Reference the package directly from the project so select a different version.**

VS2017 Publish settings that actually works: 
[image]
cmd line that doesn't work:

```
dotnet publish "c:\myproject.csproj" -f netcoreapp2.1 -c "Debug" -o "c:\users\me\dekstop\publish" --self-contained true -r win-x64
```

**EDIT added csproj contents***

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <Platforms>x64;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>False</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\GlobalInfo\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs">
        <Link>Properties\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Configuration\CrossPlatformConfiguration.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Registrations\SetupModule.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Autofac">
        <HintPath>..\..\packages\autofac\4.9.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net">
        <HintPath>..\..\packages\log4net\2.0.8\lib\netstandard1.3\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\proj1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\proj2.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\..\_Keys\Private\MyXkey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <AssemblyName>Test.Setup</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Test.Setup</RootNamespace>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

*What is happening differently  here that allows VS2017 to publish the executable?*

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Are you getting an error message, if so what message? We need more information.

Comment: The error message is in bold in my question above

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. Could you please post the contents of your project file?

Comment: added csproj contents

Comment: it also doesn't report any errors from the cmd line IF i remove the --self-contained and -r win-x64 switches.  not sure why, since those are present when Visual Studio does it!

Comment: I would try adding TargetLatestRuntimePatch and setting it to true in the project file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192979/discussion-between-theodosius-von-richthofen-and-programmerman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProgrammerMan led me to the solution, which was to add

```
<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1605</NoWarn>
```

to the csproj of each project in the solution.

Comment: Actually it was [@Martin-Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784387/martin-ullrich). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but some more information that may eventually help towards a 'real' solution...

I believe you will find the same NU1605 errors in VS2017, but the difference is they are treated as warnings so the publish completes successfully.
After publishing you can see the warnings in the Output window - **View** > **Output** and then **Show output from: Build**.

- I find the errors/warning are linked to the target runtime (-r) and anything
  other than 'Portable' (or blank) will cause them.
- I have updated to .NET Core 2.2.107 and still get them.
- I also get the same with my .NET Standard 2.0 project.
- I have also muted them by adding the same NoWarn suggestion.